# Why does the greet function not return the expected value?

Tags: javascript

Question:

Why does the greet function not return the expected value?

Code:

```
function Person(name){
    this.name = name;
}

Person.prototype.greet = function(otherName){
     return "Hi" + otherName + ", my name is " + name;
}
```

How do I answer this? I create a new person then what do I do?

```
var John = new Person("John");
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Wrong access method. the variable `name` isn't defined, only `this.name` is defined. So it's looking for a variable in the function scope called `name` instead of a property of the object called `name`.

To access an object's property from within the object we use the `this` keyword. Thus we'll need to use `this.name` to access the `name` property in the implementation below.

```
Person.prototype.greet = function(otherName){
     return "Hi" + otherName + ", my name is " + this.name;
}
```

Comment: Object property resolution has nothing to do with scope. The phrase "Wrong scope" would be better as "wrong access method".

Answer (score 5):

In your code:

```
> function Person(name) {
>     this.name = name;
> }
```

When called as a constructor, the above will create a named property of an instance called *name* and assign it the value of the *name* parameter.

```
> Person.prototype.greet = function(otherName){
>     return "Hi" + otherName + ", my name is " + name;
> }
```

Here the identifier *name* is used as a variable, but the identifier you are looking for is a named property of the instance, so you need to access it at as such. Typically, this function will be called as a method of the instance so *this* within the function will be a reference to the instance. So you want:

```
      return "Hi" + otherName + ", my name is " + this.name;
```

So now when you can do (note that variables starting with a capital letter are, by convention, reserved for construtors):

```
> var john = new Person("John");
```

and then:

```
john.greet('Fred');
```

because *greet* is called as a method of *john*, it will return:

```
Hi Fred, my name is John
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, since this is an issue of scope inheritance (second function not having access to the variable "name"), we can rephrase the code to look like this to include it all under the Person function:

```
function Person(name){
   this.name = name;
   this.greet = function(otherName){
      return "Hi" + otherName + ", my name is " + name;
    }
}
```

Works as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the greet function to use the object's name with the `this` keyword:

```
Person.prototype.greet = function(otherName){
     return "Hi" + otherName + ", my name is " + this.name;
}
```

after that, just call `John.greet("other name");`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
function Person(name){
   this.name = name;
   this.greet = function(otherName){
      return "Hi " + otherName + ", my name is " + name;
    }
} 

Person("Joe")
greet("Kate")
```